# Testing Django Rest Framework POST returns 500 despite call working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Update**

This issue was caused by me not including a token in the APIClient's header. This is resolved.

---

I have a standard ModelViewSet at `/test-endpoint`. I am trying to use APIClient to test the endpoint.

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
... # During this process, a file is uploaded to S3. Could this cause the issue? Again, no errors are thrown. I just get a 500.
self.client = APIClient()
...
sample_call = {
    "name": "test_document",
    "description": "test_document_description"
}
response = self.client.post('/test-endpoint', sample_call, format='json')
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

This call works with the parameters I set in sample_call. It returns a 201. When I run the test, however, I get a 500. How can I modify this to get the 201 passed?

I run the tests with `python src/manage.py test modulename`

---

To rule out the obvious, I copy-pasted the sample call into Postman and run it without issue. I believe the 500 status code is coming from the fact that I'm testing the call and not using it in a live environment.

---

No error messages are being thrown beyond the AssertionError:

> AssertionError: 500 != 201

**Full Output of testing**

```
/home/bryant/.virtualenvs/REDACTED/lib/python3.4/site- packages/django_boto/s3/shortcuts.py:28: RemovedInDjango110Warning:  Backwards compatibility for storage backends without support for the     `max_length` argument in Storage.get_available_name() will be removed in Django 1.10.
s3.save(full_path, fl)

F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_create (sample.tests.SampleTestCase)
Test CREATE Document
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bryant/api/redacted/src/sample/tests.py", line 31, in test_create
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
AssertionError: 500 != 201

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.673s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

The S3 warning is expected. Otherwise, all appears normal.

Comment: Can it be some difference in settings? Check `response.content` what's in it?

Comment: Also, can you add the full output of `python src/manage.py test modulename`?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll get this up tomorrow

Comment: Added test output

Comment: Hm. I was sure there should be an error log when 500 happens. Anyway, the second option. Can you `print(response.content)` one line above the assertion? What's there? You have DEBUG set to True in your test settings, right?

Comment: Could you add the view please?

Comment: So sorry, issue was caused because I forgot to authenticate the user in the test. Resolved :)

Answer (score 4):

To debug a failing test case in Django/DRF:

- Put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` just before the assertion and see the `request.content` as suggested by @Igonato, or you can just add a `print(request.content)`, there is no shame for it.
- Increase verbosity of your tests by adding `-v 3`
- Use dot notation to investigate the specific test case: `python src/manage.py test modulename.tests.<TestCase>.<function>`

I hope these are useful to keep in mind.